# Calculating Length of Sequences from .PBS File

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am new here. I am looking for help in a bioinformatics type task I have. The task was to calculate the total length of all the sequences in a .pbs file.

The file when opened, displays something like :

The Length is 102

The Length is 1100

The Length is 101

The Length is 111200

The Length is 102

I see that the length is given like a list, with letters and numbers. I need help figuring out what python code to write to add all the lengths together. Not all the sums are the same.

So far my code is:

```
f = open('lengthofsequence2.pbs.o8767272','r')

lines = f.readlines()

f.close()

def lengthofsequencesinpbsfile(i):

    for x in i:

        if

            return x +=

print lengthofsequencesinpbsfile(lines)
```

I am not sure what to do with the for loop. I want to just count the numbers after the statement "The Length is..."

Thank You!

Answer (score -1):

`"The Length is "` has 14 characters so `line[14:]` will give you the substring corresponding to the number you are after (starting after the 14th character), you then just have to convert it to `int` with `int(line[14:])` before adding to your total: `total += int(line[14:])`

Comment: I am not running this process locally either. I am running it on an HPC cluster. So I will be creating a Python script first, then inserting that script onto a PBS script.

Comment: So what? I don't understand how that relates to your question.

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to parse your input to get the data you want to work with.
   a.  x.replace('The Length is ','') - this removes the unwanted text.
   b.  int(x.replace('The Length is ','')) - convert digit characters to
       an integer
2. Add to a total: total += int(x.replace('The Length is ',''))

All of this is directly accessible using google.  I looked for python string functions and type conversion functions.  I've only looked briefly at python and never programmed with it, but I think these two items should help you do what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks man... I looked it up, and it kept failing when I tried it. That is why I came here.... For some help.